# How to acces tabbarcontroller from another Page?

Tags: flutter, navigation, tabbar

I want to acces the tabbarview from another page. So that I can immediately acces the third tabbarview by on button click. Without going to the first page. How is this possible?

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => firstpage()), // here i want immediately go to third page
    );
  },
);
```

When I insert the third page as the MaterialPageRout my app and tabbar is missing.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
Home({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);



final int title;
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return HomeExtended();
 }

}

class HomeExtended extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

//here I want to acces the title from home 
// when I add super(key: key) it marks the key
// I think its because it is not a stateful widget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have the following app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

add the following to `TabBarDemo` class

```
final int initialIndex;
TabBarDemo({Key key, this.initialIndex}) : super(key: key);
```

edit the `DefaultTabController` to:

```
//...
DefaultTabController(
     length: 3,
     initialIndex: initialIndex??0,
//...
```

then when routing to the TabBarDemo class you can call it like:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => TabBarDemo(initialIndex:2)),
);
```

Edit:
if you are using `StatefulWidget` & its state is another class that extends `State`, in the state class you can access the stateful widget through the keyword `widget`.

```
initialIndex: widget.initialIndex??0,
```

Comment: Almost working. Thanks. I can acces the value from the stateful widget. The problem is I have a class which extends the State from the Stateful Widget and I dont know how to acces the value from there. This is the class where the controller is located.I Edited the code above.

Comment: You can access the stateful widget inside the state using the keyword `widget`. I edited the answer.